# Azure Automation DSC - Permission and Module Issues

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

Are there any Azure Automation DSC gurus who can help with some guidance and know-how for pushing through a couple impasses I am currently encountering?

The task at hand is:  Use Azure Automation Runbook to provision a VM.  That VM should immediately be associated with a DSC configuration, which will adjust Windows features, settings, and install SQL Server according to a specific configuration.  All tasks conducted need to be written in PowerShell and should require no manual input via Azure portal at any point.

At this time, the Runbook provisioning the VM is working perfectly.  However, associating this new node with a DSC configuration is still a manual process, which also is working (with the exception of the next issue mentioned below).  However, this process needs to be automated instead.  How is this done?  Via DSC resources as children of the VM resource in the ARM template?

Getting SQL Server installed is the next step.  The xSQLServer DSC module seemed perfect for achieving this, but it currently has a [bug in Azure Automation](https://github.com/PowerShell/xSQLServer/issues/713), which means that the xSQLServerSetup resource is not available, even when using older versions of xSQLServer.  So, there appear to be two possible workarounds to this…

Workaround 1:  Not use xSQLServer and just run a PS script that is local on the newly provisioned VM to install SQL Server using a command line installation using an INI file.  The PS script to install SQL works, but only when run manually.  When attempting to have DSC run this script, Azure is throwing an error that the script is not digitally signed.  So, there appears to be a permissions scoping issue at play, and the DSC credential is not able to run the local PS script even though the local admin credential is being passed in.  How does one get around this?

Workaround 2:  Apparently, it is supposed to be possible to provision a VM, compile the DSC MOF local on that machine (with the full version of xSQLServer), and then push that registration back to Azure Automation.  Though, it is unclear how exactly this would be done, as it appears to also require the execution of a local PS script, thus providing the same impasse as the first workaround.  Is this perhaps via a Custom Script extension in the ARM template, or…?

I can see all of the parts in play, and I’ve found several helpful resources online that give breadcrumbs to the solution.  But, the breadcrumbs are too far apart, and the proper way of wiring everything together is proving to be elusive.  So, I’m here humbly asking for help and guidance in getting this worked out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all that's a lot of questions instead of 1.

1. unless this is some kind of homework - there is no point in installing sql on a vm, there are a lot of vm + sql images in Azure and it would take 5 minutes instead of 60 to provision such a vm.
2. `When attempting to have DSC run this script, Azure is throwing an error that the script is not digitally signed.` - this means your script is not signed (not related to rights\permissions), look for `execution policy`, you need to set it to unrestricted before running your script (but you don't need to, because of the first point).
3. you compile mof or upload it and then you can "tie" a vm to that mof, it can be automated with powershell (both parts), there are a lot of guides on how to do that. Like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-compile#compiling-a-dsc-configuration-with-windows-powershell)

As a general rule, use arm template to do the whole thing, again, there are lots of examples on how to achieve that (just browse [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) repo). Provisioning infrastructure with powershell (on azure) is not the best way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...

1.  It's not homework.  It's a client requirement.  VM+SQL images out of the box are not sufficient or allowed, due to the very specific VM setup and SQL installation requirements (e.g. Data files must be on the G drive  which is a striped set of 8 SSDs, Log Files must be on the H drive which is a striped set of 6 SSDs, etc, etc.

Comment: 2.  I've tried the Execution Policy adjustment from several different locations, including the DSC config, a Custom Script resource within said DSC config, a local PS policy change before calling the SQL install script, and inside the PS SQL install script).  It does not work from any of them.  The same error arises every time.

Comment: 3.  The articles about compiling MOF locally and tying that back to Azure Automation are all speaking from the perspective of being logged in to the newly provisioned VM.  This is not possible.  This work needs to take place from the DSC or ARM level, so that manual manipulation of the VM is not required.  And, running such a script from DSC or ARM results in the previous error of script not being digitally signed.

Comment: 1 - nothing prevents you from reconfiguring installed sql (and its 10 times faster). 2 - you need to adjust execution policy before executing your script, not during said process, so a custom script extension modifying execution policy and after that launch your dsc. 3 - i'm not really sure how to get that across to you, you compile once and assign vms to mofs. it doesnt have to happen during vm provisioning. even if it did, all of this is possible with powershell from azure automation\powershell script\arm template

Comment: again, even if your clients wants a very specific setup its your duty to implement it in a better way vs sluggish way.

Comment: Thank you again for your feedback.  To your point #1, how is this done?  I am unable to find any resources online describing this process.   To your point #2, thank you.  That helps. I will look into that.  To your point #3, because of the xSQLServer bug, according to the bug documentation I linked, the MOF must be compiled on every local machine and associated with Azure Automation as part of provisioning.  Maybe the info from point 2 will help accomplish this, but the exact steps and methodology are still unclear.  Do you know of any resources that explain this?

Comment: 1. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-agent-extension) or old module xsql or scripts (possible can be done with configuration file, dont quote me on that). 3. if you do not need to change anything in the mof you can compile it once and link nodes to that mof (or compile several mofs, its not like every server you have is unique).